# UITableView crashing with reloadRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have an iPad iOS app where a tableview is displayed on the left side of the view and a data-entry form is displayed on the right side.  The right-hand data entry form is comprised of another tableview with UITextFields within the cells.

When a particular textfield is changed then I need to change the corresponding row within the left-hand table.  I am managing this using notifications.  Most of the time it all works fine, but sometimes the app crashes when I attempt to update the particular row within the left-hand table.

The left-side tableview is being managed by a different view controller to the right-hand table.

The right-hand table textfield has the following method within its view controller:

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender
{
    switch (((UIView*)sender).tag) {
        case TAG_QE_PAGECAPTIONTEXTFIELD:
            NSLog(@" = = = = = Caption did change %@",((UITextField*)sender).text);
            [getModelForm() updateCurrentPageCaption:((UITextField*)sender).text forLanguage:@"English"];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"pageCaptionWasChanged" object: @"PageEdit"];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

The viewcontroller for the left-hand table establishes a listener for the notification with the following code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(eventPageCaptionWasChanged:)
     name: @"pageCaptionWasChanged"
     object: nil];
```

The view controller for the left-hand table then has the following method:

```
-(void)eventPageCaptionWasChanged:(id)alteredText
{

    UITableView* tableView = (UITableView*)[ self.view viewWithTag:TAG_QE_PAGELIST_TABLEVIEW ];
    int row = (int)getModelForm().currentPageNo;
    NSLog(@"HPSQuestionnaireEditorController got eventPageCaptionWasChanged with %@ for row %i",alteredText,row);
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
    NSArray* array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
    int modelPageCount = getModelForm().pages.count;
    NSLog(@"eventPageCaptionWasChanged modelPageCount=%i",modelPageCount);
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}
```

The app intermittently crashes on the `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` line.  The exception is:
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:1037

Can anyone help?

Thanks very much.

Comment: try to put the code in the `-(void)eventPageCaptionWasChanged:(id)alteredText` method in a try-catch block and print out the exception. I'm thinking of an out of bounds exception , but printing it will give us more clues.

Comment: The debugger reports the exception as : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 2 from section 0 which only contains 2 rows before the update'.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the page numbers are starting at 1, but the table indexes start at zero, so when you look for a row numbered 2 the table is actually searching for a 3rd item i.e. 0,1,2 and is therefore is getting an out of bounds exception.

Easiest way to fix it would be to change this line.

```
int row = (int)getModelForm().currentPageNo;
```

to this

```
int row = (int)getModelForm().currentPageNo -1;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer.  It does look like that sort of problem, but it actually isn't an indexing problem (there is always an additional first row added to the table).  Also, the problem is intermittent, and only happens occasionally.  It is fine (and the table looks the same) if I use reloadData, but not if I try refreshing just one row.

Comment: The error message tells you that row index 2 is tried to be deleted while the biggest index is 1 (there are 2 rows.) Your app is probably always crasing when you try to delete the last row. Correcting the indexing should solve the issue. Also you may convert to modern obj-c for array initialization and such. It's much more concise.

Comment: To confirm that you delete the right row, make sure that the items are different. Deleting from "item, item, item" will not reveal such issues. "item1, item2, item3" is much better for that.